# Is there any way in .NET to do attribute based logging apart from PostSharp

Tags: .net, aop, postsharp

I want similar functionalities like PostSharp in my code like the onEntry and onExit method invoked by attributes on a function. Are there any alternatives to the same thing?

Cant use PostSharp as it is not opensource and I cant use a 3rd party library in my project.

Comment: Besides this seeming like a tool request - if there's an obvious tool for the job and you're *rejecting* the use of that tool, it helps for you to give the specific *reasons* for avoiding that tool, because a) those same reasons may also preclude other "obvious" (but unknown to you) approaches, and b) those reasons may actually be based on a misunderstanding on your part.

Comment: An alternative to Postsharp is to use the MethodDecorator Fody package.  It works the same way, you'll find it on github.  If you don't want to use third party code the only option is to write it yourself?

Comment: @PatrickAllwood can u provide a sample application on how to use MethodDecorator Fody package. I tried running it but the onentry method of custom attribute is not executing.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of anything as powerfull as postsharp.

If The free Version of postsharp doesn't meet your needs there are some other frameworks to look at such as unity

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg490353.aspx

However where postsharp is transparent unity aop is not. It only works on unity intercepted interfaces (and intercepted the right way). Also if I remember correctly there are some other limitations like it doent play nice with tracked entities from entity framework if I remember correctly.

Another free way is you could write linq extensions. It's not aop but you can write code like

```
Linqhelper.log().cache().execute(some method)
```

Also not transparent like postsharp but it might suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use MrAdvice.Sharp . 
Although PostSharp is far better, MrAdvice.Sharp is free and it has your needs. 
Usage is almost same with Postsharp.